# Eclipse Mars Android SDK Plugin location

Tags: android, eclipse-mars

Where is the file location for the plugins downloaded using Eclipse marketplace in Eclipse Mars? I downloaded the Android SDK but the plugins folder is not created in the eclipse folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can see and change the SDK folder location in **Window > Preferences > Android.**

Comment: For some reason the SDK location is set to one of my older eclipse installation paths and is not valid now. Installing the android plugin with my current version of eclipse does not change that path. How can that be resolved?

Comment: I guess you'll have to search where is the new SDK folder and then put its location it in the Eclipse's preferences.

Comment: Not able to find that way!